# Posting data from Controller to external URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing payment system for a company, and usind a 3D secure model. Basicaly i need to post a data to the bank as below :

```
<form method="post" action="https://<sunucu_adresi>/<3dgate_path>">
                ....
</form>
```

And bank is returning some values ? How can i post to this URL from controller to take returning parameters ?

Regards.

Possible Solution #1 and Question ( @elolos )

Here is my 2 action in NewPayment controller . 
And I am calling  http://localhost.com:34324/NewPayment/PostTo3D but getting 404 error. I dont know async functions actually, i think this 404 is about my fault ? How should i call this async function ?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult umut(string bb) {
        ViewBag.Message = bb;
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTo3D()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bb", "Hello Worlds")
    });

        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        return await client.PostAsync("http://localhost.com:34324/NewPayment/umut", content);

    }
```

Comment: You can use the same HTML in your views.

Comment: Look at next classes: `HttpClient`, `WebClient` or `WebRequest`, you can use any of them for your purposes.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları How can i get the returning values in the view ?

Comment: Returning values are probably redirected to some other URL in your application. You may be including a return URL in your form. Check out the API documentation.

Comment: for good reasons , its good if you do not post data directly to the secure gateway , rather use APIs suggested by @Uriil and from server side request to the gateway...

Comment: @vishalsharma for security reaosons ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you get a 404 error when posting to the PostTo3D task or does the client call return a 404? Have you tried debugging the Action and see the code is ever reached? You could also try directly sending POST requests by using tools like Fiddler or the chrome extension POSTMAN.

Comment: I just call the PostTo3D action from url. And wait for the post to my internal link which map the different action in same controller

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 var url = "http://www.somepaymentprovider.com";
Response.Clear();
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>");
sb.AppendFormat("<form action='{0}' method='post'>", url);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='now' value='{0}'>", strId);
sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='random' value='{0}'>", random);
sb.Append("</form>");
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.Append("</html>");
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, here's a simplistic example:

```
[HttpPost]
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostTo3D() 
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("someField", "value")
        });

    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    return await client.PostAsync("https://<sunucu_adresi>/<3dgate_path>", content);

}
```

Comment: It depends on what the service you post to expects. If it expects a form, add KeyValuePairs for each of the fields like in the example. If it expects a complex type DTO then you need to have a different approach.

Comment: I am getting this error : "Error 8 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'string' C:\Users\uguncanmac\Desktop\Projects\TebSanalOdeme\ModulericaV1\Controllers\NewPaymentController.cs 57 20 ModulericaV1
"

Comment: @elolos I think if you use `FormUrlEncodedContent`, you don't have to specify ContentType Header explicitely

Comment: @Uriil, you're right, when I've edited the example to use 'FormUrlEncodedContent' instead of string, I forgot to remove the header. It certainly doesn't hurt having it there.

Comment: @umki I've updated the example, the error you were getting was because the PostAsync() method returns HttpResponseMessage and not string.